# Can SPI and serial.begin be used at the same time?

Tags: spi

I have two modules where I want to control them through a single Arduino UNO.

I guess Serial.begin(9600) uses serial port and UART. But Im not sure about SPI.

Can I use SPI library hence the SPI communication together with serial communication(serial.begin) at the same time to communicate with two different modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. UART and SPI are completely different things.  One uses pins 0/1, the other uses pins 11/12/13, and they use separate hardware and control registers inside the chip.

Comment: Thanks is it possible to use some other pin than pin 11 for SPI? Im currently using 8 9 10 and 11 for another module.

Comment: No. 11/12/13 are SPI. That can not be changed. Ever. It's written in stone (well, silicon, which is what most stone is made of).  You *could* bit-bang SPI using `shiftIn()` and `shiftOut()` on other pins if you don't need any great speed or full duplex operation if you really want.

Comment: I see then I will try to change the other module's pins.

Comment: @atomant if you're using a "Software SPI" you can use as default wired of SPI on your module. else if you're using a "Hardware SPI" you can define another pinout as SPI wire!!